# CSS keyframe animation: translate3d is not visible in IE10 and IE11

Tags: css, css-animations, internet-explorer-10

I have animation running continuously which moves a element(arrow) from **right to left** then **rotate** *180deg* and move from **left to right**. For some reasons, animation is not visible in *IE10* but arrow appears in left and right position.

Overall, animation happens but translate3d animation (move from left to right and right to left) is not visible.

```
@keyframes moveRightToLeft {
    0% {
        -moz-transform: rotateZ(0deg) translate3d(0%, 0, 0);
        -webkit-transform: rotateZ(0deg) translate3d(0%, 0, 0);
        -o-transform: rotateZ(0deg) translate3d(0%, 0, 0);
        -ms-transform: rotateZ(0deg) translate3d(0%, 0, 0);
        transform: rotateZ(0deg) translate3d(0%, 0, 0);
        opacity: 1;
    }
    50% {
        -moz-transform: rotateZ(0deg) translate3d(-80%, 0, 0);
        -webkit-transform: rotateZ(0deg) translate3d(-80%, 0, 0);
        -o-transform: rotateZ(0deg) translate3d(-80%, 0, 0);
        -ms-transform: rotateZ(0deg) translate3d(-80%, 0, 0);
        transform: rotateZ(0deg) translate3d(-80%, 0, 0);
        opacity: 0;
    }
    51% {
        -moz-transform: rotateZ(180deg) translate3d(0%, 13px, 0);
        -webkit-transform: rotateZ(180deg) translate3d(0%, 13px, 0);
        -o-transform: rotateZ(180deg) translate3d(0%, 13px, 0);
        -ms-transform: rotateZ(180deg) translate3d(0%, 13px, 0);
        transform: rotateZ(180deg) translate3d(0%, 13px, 0);
        opacity: 0;
    }
    75% {
        -moz-transform: rotateZ(180deg) translate3d(-40%, 13px, 0);
        -webkit-transform: rotateZ(180deg) translate3d(-40%, 13px, 0);
        -o-transform: rotateZ(180deg) translate3d(-40%, 13px, 0);
        -ms-transform: rotateZ(180deg) translate3d(-40%, 13px, 0);
        transform: rotateZ(180deg) translate3d(-40%, 13px, 0);
        opacity: 1;
    }
    100% {
        -moz-transform: rotateZ(180deg) translate3d(-80%, 13px, 0);
        -webkit-transform: rotateZ(180deg) translate3d(-80%, 13px, 0);
        -o-transform: rotateZ(180deg) translate3d(-80%, 13px, 0);
        -ms-transform: rotateZ(180deg) translate3d(-80%, 13px, 0);
        transform: rotate(180deg) translate3d(-80%, 13px, 0);
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with my CSS animation in Internet Explorer 10 and 11 was using percentage(%) value for one axis and pixel(px) value for other axis in **translate3d**. I was able to fix the bug moving to pixel based value for all axis in **translate3d**

```css
@keyframes moveRightToLeft {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: rotateZ(0deg) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        -ms-transform: rotateZ(0deg) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        transform: rotateZ(0deg) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    }
    50% {
        -webkit-transform: rotateZ(0deg) translate3d(-70px, 0, 0);
        -ms-transform: rotateZ(0deg) translate3d(-70px, 0, 0);
        transform: rotateZ(0deg) translate3d(-70px, 0, 0);
        opacity: 1;
    }
    51% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: rotateZ(0deg) translate3d(-75px, 0px, 0);
        -ms-transform: rotateZ(0deg) translate3d(-75px, 0px, 0);
        transform: rotateZ(0deg) translate3d(-75px, 0px, 0);
    }
    52% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: rotateZ(180deg) translate3d(75px, 0px, 0);
        -ms-transform: rotateZ(180deg) translate3d(75px, 0px, 0);
        transform: rotateZ(180deg) translate3d(75px, 0px, 0);
    }
    55% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    75% {
        -webkit-transform: rotateZ(180deg) translate3d(40px, 0px, 0);
        -ms-transform: rotateZ(180deg) translate3d(40px, 0px, 0);
        transform: rotateZ(180deg) translate3d(40px, 0px, 0);
        opacity: 1;
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotateZ(180deg) translate3d(0px, 0px, 0);
        -ms-transform: rotateZ(180deg) translate3d(0px, 0px, 0);
        transform: rotate(180deg) translate3d(0px, 0px, 0);
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

It is interesting why IE cannot work with pixel for one axis and percentage value for other axis? For future use, thing to keep in mind.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you've made browser specific transforms (which is good), but you have not made a browser specific keyframe. I believe this is where your problem lies. I've shortened your animation somewhat for convenience, but try something like this:

```
@keyframes moveRightToLeft {
    0% {
        transform: rotateZ(0deg) translate3d(0%, 0, 0);
        opacity: 1;
    }
    100% {
        transform: rotate(180deg) translate3d(-80%, 13px, 0);
        opacity: 0;
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes moveRightToLeft {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: rotateZ(0deg) translate3d(0%, 0, 0);
        opacity: 1;
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg) translate3d(-80%, 13px, 0);
        opacity: 0;
    }
}

@-moz-keyframes moveRightToLeft {
    0% {
        -moz-transform: rotateZ(0deg) translate3d(0%, 0, 0);
        opacity: 1;
    }
    100% {
        -moz-transform: rotate(180deg) translate3d(-80%, 13px, 0);
        opacity: 0;
    }
}

@-o-keyframes moveRightToLeft {
    0% {
        -o-transform: rotateZ(0deg) translate3d(0%, 0, 0);
        opacity: 1;
    }
    100% {
        -o-transform: rotate(180deg) translate3d(-80%, 13px, 0);
        opacity: 0;
    }
}

@-ms-keyframes moveRightToLeft {
    0% {
        -ms-transform: rotateZ(0deg) translate3d(0%, 0, 0);
        opacity: 1;
    }
    100% {
        -ms-transform: rotate(180deg) translate3d(-80%, 13px, 0);
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
```

also remember to declare your animations with the prefixes like this:

```
animation-name: moveRightToLeft;
-webkit-animation-name: moveRightToLeft;
-moz-animation-name: moveRightToLeft;
-o-animation-name: moveRightToLeft;
-ms-animation-name: moveRightToLeft;
```

As well as on your other animation properties. From experience, all browsers usually work with just the plain and the -webkit- prefix, but throwing in the other prefixes should guarantee it. You might also want to consider using an auto-prefixer in your IDE in the future to save yourself the copy pasting.

I hope this solves it.

Comment: The animation is happening but transform3d is not visible. At first, arrow visible at right side then disappears after some and appears in left hand side with rotation. The problem I have is translate3d is not visible.